# Is the string "abc" the same as "bca" in an unordered_set?

Tags: c++, string, unordered-set

I want to utilize a `std::unordered_set` to store a bunch of strings. If I insert the strings `"abc"`, `"def"`, `"bca"`, what would the resulting set contain?

`set = { {"abc"}, {"def"}, {"bca"} }`

Or

`set = { {"abc"}, {"def"} }`

??

Since strings `"abc"` and `"bca"` have the same characters even though they are not exactly equal.

Comment: You could provide a hash function that treats "abc" and "bca" as the same but that's not what the default hash does.

Answer (score 8):

`unordered_set` means the ordering of the elements **within** the set is irrelevant (a.k.a. {1, 2, 3} and {2, 1, 3} are equivalent). It does **not** mean that the ordering of the actual value of the element is irrelevant. "abc" and "bca" are different strings and hence have different values, so your set has 3 unique elements.

Comment: You can think of it this way.  A container never has insight into the contents of one of its elements.  All it can do is things like equality comparisons, ordering comparisons, and such.

Comment: @Tumblewee53 in this generality what you are saying is wrong. Anyhow I suppose it was for OP actually